# Prove that this type of alternating series admits this supremum.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, dirichlet-series

Let $a_k\geq 0$ be a decreasing to zero numerical sequence. How how can we prove this inequality ?
$$ \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} (-1)^k a_k\right| \leq |a_n|$$

It may have something to do with Dirichlet's test or with Leibniz criterion, but I didn't find how to show it.

Comment: It indeed is part of Leibniz' criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_i = a_i - a_{i+1}$ for all natural number $i$.

Then $b_i >0$, and 
$$a_n = \sum\limits_{i=n}^\infty b_i.$$

$$
\begin{split}
|a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}+a_{n+3}-a_{n+4}+\ldots| & = |b_{n+1} + b_{n+3} + \ldots| \\
 & = b_{n+1} + b_{n+3} + \ldots \\
 & < b_n + b_{n+1} + b_{n+2}+ b_{n+3} + \ldots = a_n
\end{split}
$$